# Help printing MIPS array of 5 - 15

Tags: mips

I am trying to understand arrays in MIPS and am having a really hard time in doing so. The array that i am working with look like this in C++:

```
int array [10];
void main(){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){   
    array[i] = i + 5;  
  }  
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){  
    cout << array[i] << endl;  
  }  
  return 0;  
}
```

I have this MIPS code so far but it has errors and prints all `0`'s:

```
.data  
array: .space 40  
    .globl main  
    .text  
<code>main:  
li $t0, 0               # i=0  
li $t4, 0               # i=0 for print loop   
li $s1, 10              # $s1 = 10  
la $a1, array           # loads array to $a1  

LOOP:  
bge  $t0, $s1, print    # branch to print if i<10  
addi $t1, $t0, 5        # i+5  

add $t2, $t1, $t1       # 2 * i  
add $t2, $t2, $t2       # 4 * i  
add $t2, $t2, $a1       # $t2=address of array[i]  
sw  $t3, 0($t2)  
addi $t0, $t0, 1        # i++  
j LOOP                  # jumps to top of loop  

print:  
bge $t4, $s1, exit      # branch to exit if i < 10  
add $t5, $t4, $t4       # 2 * i  
add $t5, $t5, $t5       # 4 * i  
add $t5, $t5, $a1       # $t2=address of array[i]  
sw  $t6, 0($t5)  

li  $v0, 1  
move $a0, $t6           #moves value to $a0 to be printed  
syscall  

addi $t4, $t4, 1        # i++  
j print                 # jumps to top of print  


 exit:  
li $v0, 10                      #load value for exit   
syscall                         #exit program
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 errors:

```
add $t2, $t1, $t1       # 2 * i
```

should be

```
add $t2, $t0, $t0       # 2 * i
```

because `$t1 = $t0 + 5`

Secondly,

```
sw  $t3, 0($t2)
```

should be

```
sw  $t1, 0($t2)
```

Finally,

```
sw  $t6, 0($t5)
```

should be

```
lw  $t6, 0($t5)
```